# How to add <> to code sample. C# generics need. 

Tags: discussion, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Please help me. Few hours already achieved nothing since nobody seems to understands my question.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: You need to ask this question on http://meta.stackoverflow.com. But you can either use the back tick \` or indent by four spaces to get code including `<` and `>`

Comment: I've fixed the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585439/how-to-implement-class-with-collection-of-string-object-pairs-so-that-an-object-c

Answer (score 2):

Indent each line of code with four spaces.

```
var x = new Whatever<int>();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need code inline, including code containing HTML meta characters, use backticks to set it off: ex: `IEnumerable<T>`